# Integral of arctan form

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral without techniques ($u$-sub/parts), just simplifying and inspection:

$$
\int \dfrac{1}{4+x^{2}}dx
$$

I notice an $\arctan$ form, but that $4$ in the denominator is confusing me, if there was a multiplying factor in front of the $x$ I would know what to do, but stumped on this case.

Comment: Try the substitution $x = 2\tan \theta$  When you square it something nice will happen.

Comment: Notice that $4=2^2$ so in this case $\arctan$ fits perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that
$$
\int \dfrac{1}{a^2+x^{2}}dx = \dfrac{1}{a}\cdot \arctan \left( \dfrac{x}{a} \right) + C
$$

Comment: Wow this is really helpful! do you know where by chance i can find formulas like these for other trig identities. Thanks

Comment: There is a comprehensive list of formulas in the *Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables* by Spiegel, Lipschutz and Liu.

Comment: Much more useful is software such as *Mathematica* which contains all these integrals and many many more.

Comment: Much more useful is software such as `Maple,Rubi,Maxima,SymPy,FriCAS` which contains all these integrals and many many more

Answer (score 1):

One can take a different route with the following. Let $x = 2 t$ to obtain
\begin{align}
I &= \int \frac{dx}{4 + x^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, \int\frac{dt}{1 + t^2} = \frac{1}{4} \, \int\left(\frac{1}{1 + i t} + \frac{1}{1 - i t} \right) \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \, \left[ \frac{1}{i} \, \ln(1 + i t) - \frac{1}{i} \, \ln(1-i t)  \right] + c_{1} \\
& = \frac{1}{4i} \, \ln\left(\frac{1+i t}{1- i t}\right) + c_{1}.
\end{align}
Now using 
$$\tan^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{2i} \, \ln\left(\frac{1+ i y}{1 - i y}\right)$$
then the integral becomes, after back substitution,
$$\int \frac{dx}{4 + x^2} = \frac{1}{2} \, \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + c_{1} = \frac{1}{4i} \, \ln\left(\frac{2 +i x}{2 - i x}\right) + c_{0}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Doing $x=2y$ and $\mathrm dx=2\mathrm dy$, you get$$2\int\frac2{4+(2y)^2}\,\mathrm dy=\frac12\int\frac1{1+y^2}\,\mathrm dy.$$Can you do the rest?